# Python UDP socket not sending all packets, or not all packets are received on the other end

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, python-sockets

I'm working on an implementation of a logical data diode, which means that data can only flow in one direction. No ACKs are allowed. Therefore, I have chosen UDP. This is the gist of the protocol:

1. Split the payload into small chunks
2. Give each chunk a sequence number
3. Transmit the chunk to the receiver using UDP

For small payloads, this works flawlessly. For larger payloads, however, at around 600 datagrams sent, the packets seem to mysteriously disappear in transmit. All packets are *logged* as sent, but on the receiving end, the packets just stop.

Here is a code snippet:

```
        for i in range(redundancy + 1):
            seq = 0
            sent_bytes = 0
            bytes_to_send = len(session.encrypted_data)
            while sent_bytes < bytes_to_send:
                logger.info("Sending payload chunk %d", seq)
                header = concat_bytes(str(seq).zfill(16).encode(), session.session_uuid.bytes_le)
                remaining_room = BUFFER_SIZE - len(header)
                data = session.encrypted_data[sent_bytes : sent_bytes + remaining_room]
                payload = concat_bytes(header, data)
                self._transmit_bytes(payload)
                sent_bytes += len(data)
                seq += 1
```

`_transmit_bytes`:

```
    def _transmit_bytes(self, message: bytes):
        self.server_socket.sendto(message, self.addr)
        time.sleep(MESSAGE_DELAY)
```

The initialization of `server_socket`:

```
        self.server_socket: LDDSocket = LDDSocket(listen=False)
        so_linger_options = struct.pack("ii", 1, CLOSE_TIMEOUT)
        send_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 100  # 100 MB
        self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, so_linger_options)
        self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, send_buffer_size)
```

`LDDSocket` is an extremely simple wrapper for `socket.socket`. There is nothing you need to know about it (`listen=False` just makes it not bind).

As you can see, I have tried some tips that I found online, including:

- Setting SO_LINGER options (`CLOSE_TIMEOUT` is 10 seconds)
- Setting SO_SNDBUF options
- Before closing the socket, I'm waiting 10 seconds. I expected that I would still see packets being received during these 10 seconds, but the receiving stops well before that timeout and the subsequent `socket.close()` call happen.

The last point is done in the `__exit__` method of the "transmitter class", which is used as a context manager:

```
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        cleanup_grace_period = 10  # seconds
        logger.info("Waiting %d seconds for cleanup...", cleanup_grace_period)
        time.sleep(cleanup_grace_period)
        logger.info("Cleanup presumed to be complete; closing socket.")
        self.close()
        logger.info("Socket closed.")
```

Again, the receiving end stops receiving messages well before this `__exit__` method is called.

What could cause a socket to stop sending data after a certain amount of data has been sent? (It always ends roughly around the same sequence number, but not exactly.)

Comment: Please check with a packet capture (like wireshark) where the data get lost, i.e. if they get  transmitted at the client side and if they get received at the server side. Then you can determine if it is a problem with sending (not all data can be observed in the client), with the path between client and server (packets get lost) or with receiving the data (packet not received in server even though it can be observed in server side packet capture).

Comment: UDP provides no guarantees of delivery. If you send too quickly you may overflow the socket buffer, and the excess packets will be discarded. So you shouldn't use it if reliable delivery is needed and you don't have a method to detect loss and retransmit.

Comment: I deal with packet loss by sending the payload multiple times and dropping duplicated messages. This is supposed to run on a very simple and quiet local network, so we don't expect a lot of packet loss, especially with redundant transmissions. I suspect I'm seeing buffer overflow due to sending messages too fast, because increasing the message delay (to unacceptable levels) leads to all messages arriving. I am investigating using wireshark. Edit: The reason I don't suspect simple packet loss is that it abruptly stops at a certain seq instead of losing packets here and there.

Comment: You say you "deal with packet loss by sending the payload multiple times and dropping duplicated messages." That is insufficient for robust transmission. Especially since there is no feedback to the sender. That you run this on a "very simple and quiet local network" is irrelevant. Since (a) you don't define those terms and show the assertion to be true, and (b) there are other factors such as the receiver not processing the data fast enough.

Comment: I also see nothing in the code you included in your question that supports your assertion that you "deal with packet loss by sending the payload multiple times and dropping duplicated messages." You have either not provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or you are not accurately portraying how your program works.

Comment: Edited my question. Sending the payload multiple times: `for i in range(redundancy + 1)`. I don't consider it relevant to the question since it doesn't reach the second transmission of the payload before the packets stop being received. I'm now adding more details to the question as I found a way to make it work: Add a larger delay between each packet.

Comment: I will also point out that if a single packet is lost, even though it's sent twice, then the entire payload will be dropped. It's not the end of the world if that happens, but we want to minimize this. Luckily, we haven't seen a single example of a dropped payload besides these problems, which were decidedly NOT due to conventional packet loss.

Answer (score 0):

My problem appears to be related to buffer sizes.

An investigation revealed:

- All packets were not sent from the receiver (WireShark).
- All packets were not received by the receiver (WireShark).
- Increasing the `MESSAGE_DELAY` value to 100ms (meaning it waits 100ms after sending a packet before sending another one) caused all packets to be sent and received, but this is an unacceptable delay.
- Decreasing the `MESSAGE_DELAY` gradually increased the chance of the last packets (never any in the middle) being lost.
- Setting a send buffer size (`SO_SNDBUF`) option caused all packets to be sent (WireShark), but not received.
- Setting a receive buffer size (`SO_RCVBUF`) option caused all packets to be received.

Finally, I was able to reduce `MESSAGE_DELAY` and still receive all packets.

Comment: So you’ve tuned your application to a particular set of network conditions that obtained at the time. When the network gets busier this won’t work any more. You need an ACK-based or NACK-based protocol.

Comment: The network won't get busier. This is a dedicated line that will only ever have the transmitter on one end, the receiver on the other end, and a firewall in the middle to prevent packets going from the receiver to the transmitter (a logical data diode). ACKs are forbidden by definition in data diodes.